# GitLab-CI: How to use environment variable in services command

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I have the address of my docker registry in an GitLab-CI environment variable.

How can I use it in the context of a service command in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

```
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--insecure-registry=$CI_REGISTRY"] # this does not work

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" . # this works properly
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
```

Comment: Seems like other people have this issue too: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3808

Comment: not exactly sure why this is happening or maybe as per the above link is not yet implemented, a workaround would be to use GitLab registry of the same project to build the image and then push it to another external registry.